# How to configure EasyPG with Gpg4win or any other Windows GPG version?

Tags: microsoft-windows, gpg, encryption, pgp

I am having a hard time getting GPG to work in Emacs under Windows.

The configuration options I tried:

```
  (setq epg-gpg-program "c:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG/gpg2.exe")

  (setq epg-gpg-home-directory "C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/.gnupg")
```

Upon opening a .gpg file with Emacs 25 for Windows I get the error

```
epg-context--make: GPG error: "no usable configuration", OpenPGP
```

With Emacs 24.3 the error is
epa-file--find-file-not-found-function: Opening input file: Decryption failed,

What am I missing?

Do I need some special version of GnuPG?

Additional configuration options?

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and got it to work. Needed to spelunk through the code in epg.el and epg-config.el to determine what to fiddle with. This is what worked for me:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(epg-gpg-home-directory "c:/Users/MYUSER/AppData/Roaming/gnupg")
 '(epg-gpg-program "C:/Progra~2/gnupg/bin/gpg.exe")
 '(epg-gpgconf-program "c:/progra~2/gnupg/bin/gpgconf.exe")
)
```

My conclusions:

- epg.el needs gpgconf.exe to determine where all the programs are
- also needs the home directory for gnupg
- not sure if gpg-program also needs to be explicitly set as it is present in the output of gpgconf.exe

Give it a shot.

Comment: Should `M-: (executable-find "gpg")` returns a valid path after setting these variables? Mine returns nil after setting them. And I still have the same problem as OP before and after setting them.

Comment: Restarting Emacs puts it into effect. `eval-buffer` isn't enough, at least for me.

Comment: Doesn't work. Attempting to save/encrypt a file just hangs. Emacs 29.1 or Windows 11 with gpg4win.