# How to get "EasyPG" to work on Windows?

Tags: gpg, encryption

I have Emacs 29.1, Windows 11, GnuPG 2.4.3 (from downloading gpg4win). I tried the
[advice here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21699/how-to-configure-easypg-with-gpg4win-or-any-other-windows-gpg-version), but it doesn't work. If I start a file named `test.gpg`, and save it, I get a buffer like this:

```
Select recipients for encryption.
If no one is selected, symmetric encryption will be performed.  
- ‘m’ to mark a key on the line
- ‘u’ to unmark a key on the line
[Cancel] [OK]

  - 0B54C3C14B75C777 ...
```

With the key marked or not, if I select `[OK]`, it just hangs. Eventually I hit `C-g` to break out of it.

Anybody got this working?

The vars I set are:

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
  '(epg-gpg-program  "C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe")
  '(epg-gpg-home-directory "c:/Users/rob/AppData/Roaming/gnupg")
  '(epg-gpgconf-program "c:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpgconf.exe")
```

Comment: Can you tell us what version of `gpg` you are using?  There is an issue with versions >2.2.40 that causes a freeze.

Comment: @FranBurstall That's at the top of the question, I thought. (2.4.3) That's what came from `gpg --version`

Comment: sorry---did not read carefully enough. In any case, this seems to be a known problem (see here for example: https://irreal.org/blog/?p=11827).  Solution is to downgrade gpg to 2.4.0 (at least this worked for me on linux).

Comment: Good to know. For now, I think I'll just write some scripts to make it more convenient to encrypt my files without emacs's help.